# what is the difference between async static Task<T> someMethod() versus static async Task<T> someOtherMethod()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Can someone please explain the difference between these two implementations and explain which is a better option than other

Comment: they're exactly the same.  the order of the keywords doesn't matter here, except when your coworker stabs you for writing `static async public`

Comment: They're functionally the same. The order is preference-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the C# language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), section 10.6, "Methods":

> A method is a member that implements a computation or action that can
>   be performed by an object or class. Methods are declared using
>   *method-declarations*:
>
> *method-declaration*:
>       *method-header*  *method-body*
>
> *method-header*:
>       *attributes<sub>opt</sub>*   *method-modifiers<sub>opt</sub>*   `partial`<sub>opt</sub>   *return-type*   *member-name*   *type-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>*
>       (   *formal-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>*  )   *type-parameter-constraints-clauses<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> *method-modifiers:*
>       *method-modifier*
>       *method-modifiers*   *method-modifier*
>
> *method-modifier:*
>       `new`
>       `public`
>       `protected`
>       `internal`
>       `private`
>       `static`
>       `virtual`
>       `sealed`
>       `override`
>       `abstract`
>       `extern`
>       `async`

In other words, all of these modifiers may appear in any order. The remainder of the section specifies which combinations of modifiers are valid (modifiers may not be repeated, at most one of `static`, `virtual` or `override` may be supplied, etcetera), but it assigns no meaning to their order. Hence, there is no difference, use whatever you like (or more appropriately, whatever convention the rest of your code base has settled on, if there is one).

Note that `partial` is *not*  considered a `method-modifier` (but the section does call it a "modifier" later). This means it must appear *after* any legal modifier: `static partial void Foo()` is legal, `partial static void Foo()` is not.